# Adjacent row groups one next to another

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

In one order I can have many customers and many products.
I've got 3 tables with order details: Order_details, Order_customers and Order_products. Query to my view used as data set returns 8 rows when in one order i have 2 customers and 4 products. In Report Builder I group by Order_id but then I have got 8 row (2 customers x 4 products). If I ad group by Customer_ID and adjacent group by Product_ID then in column firs show customers id's and under product id's.
My view query looked like beneath:

```
select od.Order_id, oc.Customer_ID, oc.Customer_detail, op.Product, op.Product_detail
from Order_details od
left join Order_products op on od.Order_id = op.Order_id
left join Order_customers oc on od.Order_id = oc.Order_id
```

I want to group columns to get result looked like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
| Order ID  | Customer ID  | Customer detail | Product   | Product detail |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
|           | Customer_1   | Cusotmer_name   | Product_1 | Product1_nuber |
|  1234     |              |                 | Product_2 | Product2_nuber |
|           | Cusotmer_2   | Cusotmer_name   | Product_3 | Product3_nuber |
|           |              |                 | Product_4 | Product4_nuber |
+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this - start with the detail and then add the groups.

Example:

1. First add the 'Product' and 'Product Detail' to the report.
2. Then, right click on Product row and select 'Add Parent Group' and choose 'Customer Detail' (you may or may not add header and footer for the group).
3. Then right click the 'Customer Detail' row and select 'Add Parent Group' and choose 'Customer ID' (you may or may not add header and footer for the group).
4. Then right click the 'Customer ID' row and select 'Add Parent Group' and choose 'Order ID' (you may or may not add header and footer for the group)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I understand and done exactly how you wrote then it's not what I expact, because I still have 8 rows for one order id.

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: If I add grouping by order id then grouping by customer id as child to order id and grouping by product id as adjacent to customer id then I have something like that: 
order id | customer id and product id just under customer id,
but I want to have results like in topic.

Comment: Can you post sample output from your dataset. It's hard to see how you can tie up a customer with a product from your query.